# Impossible to connect with ldap

Tags: linux, ubuntu, authentication, ldap, openldap

## I have an open ldap server :

IP : 192.168.0.70 (dell)

DIT :

[image]

(seen through ldapphpadmin)

And for patricia duchesne:

```
dn  cn=patricia duchesne,ou=users,dc=memorandum,dc=pro
cn  patricia duchesne
gidnumber   501
givenname   patricia
homedirectory   /home/users/pduchesne
loginshell  /bin/bash
objectclass inetOrgPerson | posixAccount | top
sn  duchesne
uid pduchesne
uidnumber   1000
userpassword    {MD5}eFI0F0...
```

## Then I have an LDAP client :

IP : 192.168.0.60 (pb)

NSSWitch is configured :

```
$cat /etc/nsswitch.conf

passwd: files ldap
group: files ldap
shadow: files ldap
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files
protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
netgroup: nis
```

so is ldap-auth :

```
$ cat /etc/auth-client-config/profile.d/ldap-auth-config
[lac_ldap]
nss_passwd=passwd: files ldap
nss_group=group: files ldap
nss_shadow=shadow: files ldap
nss_netgroup=netgroup: nis
```

and libnss :

```
$ cat /etc/libnss-ldap.conf
uri ldap://192.168.0.70
base dc=memorandum,dc=pro
```

I can reach the ldap user information :

```
$ getent passwd | tail -n 1
pduchesne:*:1000:501:patricia duchesne:/home/users/pduchesne:/bin/bash
```

## But I can't connect :

From IP : 192.168.0.80

```
$ ssh pduchesne@192.168.0.60
pduchesne@192.168.0.60's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
pduchesne@192.168.0.60's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
pduchesne@192.168.0.60's password:
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

## What am I missing ?

I looked at hundred of webpages without finding a way to set up all that :(
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication
https://askubuntu.com/questions/127389/how-to-configure-ubuntu-as-an-ldap-client
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-authenticate-client-computers-using-ldap-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps

Finding this page : https://www.vincentliefooghe.net/content/openldap-gestion-des-logs
I realized I don't know where are the ldap logs :-(

## EDIT

Following : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication

PAM configuration on 192.168.0.60 :

```
$ cat /usr/share/pam-configs/my_mkhomedir
Name: activate mkhomedir
Default: yes
Priority: 900
Session-Type: Additional
Session:
        required                        pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0022 skel=/etc/skel
```

Update :

```
$ sudo pam-auth-update
[sudo] password for romain:
LDAP Password:
```

[image]

The file

```
$ cat /etc/security/group.conf
```

is fully commented

I didn't use nscd :

```
$ /etc/init.d/nscd stop
[....] Stopping nscd (via systemctl): nscd.service==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to stop 'nscd.service'.
Authenticating as: romain,,, (romain)
Password:
LDAP Password:
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
. ok
```

I didn't use the [ LDAP Host Access Authorization ] paragraph. Should I ?

## EDIT 2

Verbose ssh :

```
romain@Mac:~$ ssh -v pduchesne@pb
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to pb [192.168.0.60] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/romain/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/romain/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/romain/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/romain/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/romain/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/romain/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/romain/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/romain/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to pb:22 as 'pduchesne'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:OIiYKNK9FOdhlu2sVahXFoXYCjxmxTQ7NrZtA75Vwps
debug1: Host 'pb' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/romain/.ssh/known_hosts:18
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/romain/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/romain/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/romain/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/romain/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
pduchesne@pb's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
pduchesne@pb's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
pduchesne@pb's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

## EDIT 3

Adding user pwd hash in ldap server (see user's dump at the beginning)

## EDIT 4

Following @grawity proposal I installed libpam-ldapd:

```
romain@pb$ sudo apt-get install libpam-ldapd
[sudo] password for romain:
LDAP Password:
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  auth-client-config ldap-auth-config
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libpam-ldap
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpam-ldapd
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(...)
Setting up libpam-ldapd:amd64 (0.9.6-3) ...
```

Then I configured `/etc/nslcd.conf` on which I notice I was not specifying precising to use ldap version3 ( I don't know which version is by default ? ) :

```
romain@pb$ sudo cat /etc/nslcd.conf | grep "^[^#]"
uid nslcd
gid nslcd
uri ldap://192.168.0.70
base dc=memorandum,dc=pro
ldap_version 3
tls_cacertfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Restarted nslcd:

```
romain@pb$ sudo service nslcd restart
```

and tryed to connect from my mac :

```
romain@Mac:~$ ssh pduchesne@pb
```

which worked...kind of  :

```
romain@Mac:~$ ssh pduchesne@pb
pduchesne@pb's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-53-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

197 packages can be updated.
4 updates are security updates.

*** System restart required ***
Last login: Fri Jan 13 11:12:23 2017 from 192.168.0.80
romain@pb:~$ pwd
/home/users/pduchesne
romain@pb:~$ whoami
romain
```

## New Question (for Edit 4)

Why doesn't I change of user ??
I was expecting to log into 'pb' as 'pduchesne' :-/

## Old Question (before Edit 4)

I don't know which files to check - any advice welcome.

Comment: Have you configured PAM?

Comment: good question, which file should I  check if PAM is configured ?

Comment: seems to me PAM is configured ?

Answer (score 0):

Your shown configuration doesn't actually mention anything that could be used for authentication; i.e. no method for checking the entered password.

Your nsswitch<sup>1</sup> configuration does have `shadow: ldap`, but your dump of the user object doesn't actually mention any "shadow" attributes – so there *is* no information that `getent shadow` could retrieve. Although that's fine because exposing shadow information over LDAP wouldn't be very secure, anyway.

Instead, you should set up `pam_ldap` (libpam-ldapd), which tries to authenticate (bind) against the LDAP server using the given password. For this, it is necessary to put the LDAP-format password hash in the user's `userPassword` attribute (which is missing from your dump as well).

Note though that the standalone libnss-ldap (and libpam-ldap) has several downsides and is mostly obsolete – you'll have a much more reliable configuration with nslcd + libnss-ldap**d** + libpam-ldapd instead.

---

<sup>1</sup> "Name Service Switch", not "the Witch of NSS"

Comment: Q1 : "it is necessary to put the LDAP-format password hash in the user's userPassword attribute" => how do we do that ?

Comment: Q2 : "the user's userPassword attribute (which is missing from your dump as well)" => the dump you are referecing to is the ldap dump ? (ie : 'dn  cn=patricia duchesne,ou=users,dc=memorandum,dc=pro' etc... ?)